# Should jalapeno slices go on the pizza pre or post oven?

Tags: pizza, jalapeno

I have bought a jar of sliced jalapenos, in an attempt to make a pizza simulating the ones I used to eat as a kid. This is the first time ever I see this product for sale to normal consumers.

Now I wonder if I should put the slices on the pizza BEFORE or AFTER it's gone into the oven. I fear that they might turn into disgusting, dry lumps of coal if I put them on before, but I'm not entirely sure that it's correct to put them on when the pizza is already done (has been in the oven).

I have a feeling that the right answer is that they go on **after** the oven, but I want to make sure before I ruin my pizza tomorrow.

I can't recall what they used to do in the pizzeria, but from what I can remember (which is quite foggy), the jalapeno slices on the pizzas I used to buy after my "paper boy" route was done seemed very "preserved", as in, most likely not cooked inside the oven. I suspect that they simply sprinkled them on after the pizza has come out of the oven.

Comment: I think you'll get two different results, try both 1/2 while cooking 1/2 after

Answer (score 4):

I agree I would definitely put them on before, I don’t know of any place that puts them on after. They would just fall of the slice and be annoying. I don’t think the baking would ruin the jalapeños at all they’re pickled so they’re pretty moist, but I guess it’s possible you might prefer them slightly more “raw” but I would be pretty surprised if you did especially since you chose canned which is already very cooked. I say give it a shot putting them on before they will very likely not turn into charcoal they’re not a super thin herb.

Answer (score 1):

Ooooooh, one of my favorite toppings.

I often order pizza with Jalapenos (assuming you are talking about jarred/canned pickled Jalapenos) and like any vegetable you put it put on *before* you pop it in the oven. That will meld the Jalapeno with the cheese and any other toppings. I have done this when making my own pizza as well.

Heck you even put basil on before cooking and that comes out fine.

However, as with most food. it is all a matter of taste. No reason you can't try Jalapenos added after the pie is cooked. But I would be willing to bet you'll like it better if you cook the pizza with the jalapenos (and, ummm..., maybe some Italian sausage and mushrooms...) before you put it in the oven.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in pizza shops since 1999.  They always put on before cooking.  Theres something about hot jaleps that i just dont like.  I always put nice cold crispy jalepenos on my hot pizza afterwards.  Its just the way i like it.  I am talking about the pre packaged sliced ones pickled in a juice.  Everyone is different, try it both ways and see what you like.